# Can an Adobe AIR app that's running in the system tray pop up a window?

Tags: air

For example, if I were to write a calendar app on top of AIR, say with Flex, could this app pop up reminder windows for approaching appointments, just like Microsoft Outlook can?

Clarification: Can those windows be actual dialogs where I can enter and save information?

Comment: If it's not possible with Adobe Air, is there another way that I can develop a JavaScript app and have it pop up native Windows balloons?

Comment: Hi thvo, nice answer but i have question that how to use that i am working in FLEX 3.0 and created AIR Application so please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Creating toast-style windows](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/creating_toast-style_windows.html)

Comment: Thanks! Can those windows be actual dialogs where I can enter and save information?

Comment: Yes, they're just windows without the normal chrome.

Comment: Hi Duncan nice answer but i have question that how to use that i am working in FLEX 3.0 and created AIR Application so please help me.

Answer (score 2):

[Twhirl](http://www.twhirl.org/) pops up "toast" notifications (similiar to most instant messengers), while it is running in the system tray.

So yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are notification balloons tips but this method is going out of favor with systray icons in Windows 7 and it's not cross platform. Unfortunately, you can only call this in the Win32 API using Shell_NotifyIcon and there is no way to get to it from Air.

Stuck making your own toaster popups.

Comment: Does Windows 7 use a different API for system tray pop up notifications? This is what I'd really like to do is have native popups in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

YES

Your Flex AIR application can pop up windows, dialogs, toasters, whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/creating_toast-style_windows.html) on the Adobe Website, for creating your own Toast Style Popups.

(Credit for this goes to [Duncan Smart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278/duncan-smart), answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164311/can-an-adobe-air-app-thats-running-in-the-system-tray-pop-up-a-window).)

Comment: -1 for posting basically a copy-and-paste answer AND admitting it too.